# how to find age in zend query from date of birth

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

i am tryin to find differnce in current time and date of birth can anyone help me

to find the age from an mysql query in zend framwork the age should be greater than 21

```
       $date = Zend_Date::now(); 
   $dob = $post['dob'];

   $age = $date ->sub($dob);
       $age->toString(Y);

can this work anyone know any simple method thanks for helping
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about extracting years from database. If you using mysql, try to use this query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(dob)), '%Y')+0 AS age FROM people;
```

It’ll also work with pre and post-epoch dates.

If this method will not solve your problem, try to read about Zend_Date [comparison](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.date.basic.html#zend.date.simple.functions.compare)
but instead of
 `if ($date->compare(10, Zend_Date::MINUTE) == -1)` 
use 
`if ($date->compare(21, Zend_Date::YEAR) == -1)`

Comment: can u tell me what wrong i did in  my method no am working on zend framwork can u explain me how would thos query look like in zend framework

Comment: `$select = $db->select()->from('people', array('id', 'age' => new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(YOUR_FIELD_dob)), '%Y')+0")))`

Comment: thank you vey much my friend how can i check if age is greater then 21 or not bcos curenntly its listing me age of all user how can  i check the user who has not registerd yet and ffind if >21

Comment: its giving me age for all the user in database how can i check the minimum age of user greater than 21 in mysql when he sign ups on the register form curenntly no data is in db about the user how can i fetch it from the form or post value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384351/validate-age-before-registering-a-user-to-check-if-hes-over-a-certain-age-using-m

Comment: i have been advised to use a function in controller something like this can u help on it  function get_Age($dob){
     
  $dayinseconds = 24 * 60 * 60;
     
  $dayinYear = 0.00273972602739726;
     
     $dif = time() - $dob;
     
     $age_in_days = $dif/$dayinseconds;
     
     $flt_year = $age_in_days * $dayinYear;
     $year= floor($flt_year);
     
     
  
     return "$year yrs";

Comment: hello i have founf the answer using this                         $diff = $date ->sub($date3)->toValue();
  
 echo $years = floor(((($diff/60)/60)/24)/365);                 this gives me ages diffrence highy accurate